# Dirichlet distribution, sum of Beta distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I currently have a problem about Dirichlet distributed Variables. In one of the papers I am currently reading it says:

Let 
$S=(S_1,...,S_m)\sim Dir(\delta\omega_1,..., \delta \omega_m)$,
with $\sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j=1$ and $\delta >0$

and let
$Z=(Z_1,...,Z_m)$, with $Z_j= \sum_{i =1}^j S_i$.

Establish that:

$Z_j \sim Beta(\delta \zeta_j,\delta (1- \zeta_j))$
with $\zeta_j= \sum_{i =1}^j \omega_i$.

What I know:

I know that the marginal distribution of $S_j$ is a beta distribution with:

$
S_j \sim Beta(\delta\omega_j,\delta\sum_{i=1}^m \omega_i-\delta\omega_j)=Beta(\delta\omega_j,\delta(1-\omega_j))
$

So it looks like there is an additive characteristic.  How can this be established?

Comment: This paper provides a proof of the additive/aggregation property of the Dirichlet distribution: https://vannevar.ece.uw.edu/techsite/papers/documents/UWEETR-2010-0006.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The "additive characteristic" you speak of isn't over independent Beta variables.  It's conditional on the sum being less than 1.  That is to say, $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not independent:  although their support are on $[0,1]$, their sum cannot exceed $1$ because they are drawn from the Dirichlet distribution whose support is on $\boldsymbol S \in \{ \boldsymbol s \in [0,1]^m : \sum s_i \le 1 \}$.

Comment: Ok thank you for responding so fast!! That immediatly answers  my first question.

Any suggestion how to show:
$Z_j \sim Beta(\delta \zeta_j,\delta (1- \zeta_j))$

Comment: noone any ideas? :( just an idea how it could work helps too!